# JQUERY not working with JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 and JQUERY 1.9. I'm trying to add an attribute to a component, but when the page is rendered, the attribute is not added.

Here is the jsf code for the component.

```
  <h:form id="mainForm">
        <h:inputText id="field" value="#{bean.value}"/>
    </h:form>
```

and the jquery is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    window.onload=function(){
        $("#mainForm:field").attr("placeholder","Fill me");
    }
// <![CDATA[
</script>
```

This is being rendered like this:

```
<input id="mainForm:field" name="mainForm:field" type="text" value="">
```

Any idea on where am I wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

Change your selector to `$("#mainForm\\:field")`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, Blaze!

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the colon in the selector

```
$("#mainForm\\:field").attr("placeholder","Fill me");
```